# Can I implement if-new-create JPA strategy?

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

My current persistence.xml table generation strategy is set to create. This guarantees that each new installation of my application will get the tables, but that also means that everytime the application it's started logs are polluted with exceptions of eclipselink trying to create tables that already exist.
The strategy I wish is that the tables are created only in their absence. One way for me to implement this is to check for the database file and if doesn't exist create tables using:

```
ServerSession session = em.unwrap(ServerSession.class);
SchemaManager schemaManager = new SchemaManager(session);
schemaManager.createDefaultTables(true);
```

But is there a cleaner solution? Possibly a try-catch way? It's errorprone for me to guard each database method with a try-catch where the catch executes the above code, but I'd expect it to be a property I can configure the emf with.

Answer (score 1):

The Table creation problems should only be logged at the warning level.  So you could filter these out by setting the log level higher than warning, or create a seperate EM that mirrors the actual application EM to be used just for table creation but with logging turned off completely.

As for catching exceptions from createDefaultTables - there shouldn't be any.  The internals of createDefaultTables wrap the actual createTable portion and ignores the errors that it might throw.  So the exceptions are only showing in the log due to the log level including warning messages.  You could wrap it in a try/catch and set the session log level to off, and then reset it in the finally block though.